# Finding total number of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I have an array A consisting of N integers. I also have an integer K.
I want to find out number of different arrays I can obtain from array A by applying the following operation exactly K times.

- Pick some element in the array and multiply it by -1

array A=[2,3,2] and k=2
I have four possible arrays

1.`[2,3,2]`
2.`[-2,-3,2]`
3.`[-2,3,-2]`
4.`[2,-3,-2]`
This can be calculated as sum of  ∑<sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub> where r is {k,k-2,k-4....}.

**Edit**

But for combination of positive and negative numbers lets say our array is A=[-1,2,3] and k=3,all possible combinations are

1.`[1,2,3]` 2.`[-1,-2,3]` 3.`[-1,2,-3]` 4.`[1,-2,-3]`
 which are in total 4 arrays, which are in total 4 arrays also. 
I just submitted the code which I think should be right is

```
int main()
{
   int n,k;
   int arr[11];
   arr[0]=1;
   for (int i=1;i<=10;i++)
   {
        arr[i]=arr[i-1]*i;
        //cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
   }

    long int ans=0;
    cin>>n>>k;   / n for number of elements and k for operations
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int num;   array element
        cin>>num;
    }
    int i=(k%2==0?2:1);
    for(;i<=k;i+=2)
    {
        ans=ans+arr[n]/(arr[k]*arr[n-k]);
    }
    if(k%2==0)
        ans=arr[n]/(arr[k]*arr[n-k])+1; 
    if(n==1 && k%2==1)
        ans=1;
    cout<<ans;
}
```

But it is giving wrong answer. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: How does the existing sign suppose to change your algo?

Comment: Is there any reason why `-2,-3,-2` is not OK?

Comment: In your second example `2.[-1,-2,3]` and `4.[-1,-2,3]` are repeating, should they?

Comment: Now `3.[-1,2,-3` and `5.[-1,2,-3]` are the same

Comment: @Michi My bad. Updated.

Comment: OK, now we know what you need, but you didn't showed us what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Michi I tried till the first example. But I was unable to proceed to this problem so at last I posted here.

Comment: Now item 5 is not possible.

Comment: @Michi I think we need to consider K value, too. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh That should be interesting to do it :). Any way the OP doesn't seems to show any code which describe what he tried .

Comment: `cin` , `cout` Why the `C` tag here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This caters for a huge multidimensional setup. Some brute-force coding, using the parallel array processing language [**Dyalog APL**](http://www.dyalog.com) reveals the following number of unique results, for K = 1...10 and N = 1...14:

```
┌────┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
│    │N=1│N=2│N=3│N=4│N=5│N=6│N=7│N=8│N=9│N=10│N=11│N=12│N=13│N=14│
├────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│K=1 │1  │2  │3  │4  │5  │6  │7  │8  │9  │10  │11  │12  │13  │14  │
├────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│K=2 │1  │2  │4  │7  │11 │16 │22 │29 │37 │46  │56  │67  │79  │92  │
├────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│K=3 │1  │2  │4  │8  │15 │26 │42 │64 │93 │130 │176 │232 │299 │378 │
├────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│K=4 │1  │2  │4  │8  │16 │31 │57 │99 │163│256 │386 │562 │794 │1093│
├────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│K=5 │1  │2  │4  │8  │16 │32 │63 │120│219│382 │638 │1024│1586│2380│
├────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│K=6 │1  │2  │4  │8  │16 │32 │64 │127│247│466 │848 │1486│2510│4096│
├────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│K=7 │1  │2  │4  │8  │16 │32 │64 │128│255│502 │968 │1816│3302│5812│
├────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│K=8 │1  │2  │4  │8  │16 │32 │64 │128│256│511 │1013│1981│3797│7099│
├────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│K=9 │1  │2  │4  │8  │16 │32 │64 │128│256│512 │1023│2036│4017│7814│
├────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼────┼────┼────┼────┼────┤
│K=10│1  │2  │4  │8  │16 │32 │64 │128│256│512 │1024│2047│4083│8100│
└────┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
```

One cannot see any distinct pattern in there, although it indeed does exist. One thing we can see is that when performing the negation enough times (ie. K is "exhausts" the array), we seem to reach 2^(N-1) unique results (ie. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 etc).

Assume we do it brute-forcedly. If we have a 4-length array (ie. N=4) and K=1, elements 1, 2, 3 or 4 of the array can be negated:

```
┌─┬─┬─┬─┐
│1│2│3│4│
└─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

If K=2, we get a new a dimension (now a 2-dimensional problem) and now have 16 possible index pairs for negation:

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│1 1│1 2│1 3│1 4│
├───┼───┼───┼───┤
│2 1│2 2│2 3│2 4│
├───┼───┼───┼───┤
│3 1│3 2│3 3│3 4│
├───┼───┼───┼───┤
│4 1│4 2│4 3│4 4│
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

For example the [4 2] means that array[4] and array[2] would both be multiplied by -1.

Setting K=3 makes it 3-dimensional:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│1 1 1│1 1 2│1 1 3│1 1 4││2 1 1│2 1 2│2 1 3│2 1 4││3 1 1│3 1 2│3 1 3│3 1 4││4 1 1│4 1 2│4 1 3│4 1 4│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│1 2 1│1 2 2│1 2 3│1 2 4││2 2 1│2 2 2│2 2 3│2 2 4││3 2 1│3 2 2│3 2 3│3 2 4││4 2 1│4 2 2│4 2 3│4 2 4│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│1 3 1│1 3 2│1 3 3│1 3 4││2 3 1│2 3 2│2 3 3│2 3 4││3 3 1│3 3 2│3 3 3│3 3 4││4 3 1│4 3 2│4 3 3│4 3 4│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│1 4 1│1 4 2│1 4 3│1 4 4││2 4 1│2 4 2│2 4 3│2 4 4││3 4 1│3 4 2│3 4 3│3 4 4││4 4 1│4 4 2│4 4 3│4 4 4│
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

...where for example [1 1 1] means that array[1] would be multiplied by -1 three times in a row. Now we can also see that some of the 64 possibilities are duplicates.

When doing the brute-force calculation, there was actually 10-dimensional data involved. Eventually the system run out of memory, as the data grew enourmous.

It doesn't matter what numeric values the array contains. Instead, we of course only need to figure out the sign changes, ie. multiplications with -1. Here are the possible number of unique combinations for K = 1...5 and N = 1...5:

```
┌───┬────┬───────────┬───────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   │N=1 │N=2        │N=3                            │N=4                                                                              │N=5                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
├───┼────┼───────────┼───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=1│┌──┐│┌────┬────┐│┌──────┬──────┬──────┐         │┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐                                            │┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐                                                                                                                                                 │
│   ││-1│││-1 1│1 -1│││-1 1 1│1 -1 1│1 1 -1│         ││-1 1 1 1│1 -1 1 1│1 1 -1 1│1 1 1 -1│                                            ││-1 1 1 1 1│1 -1 1 1 1│1 1 -1 1 1│1 1 1 -1 1│1 1 1 1 -1│                                                                                                                                                 │
│   │└──┘│└────┴────┘│└──────┴──────┴──────┘         │└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘                                            │└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘                                                                                                                                                 │
├───┼────┼───────────┼───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=2│┌─┐ │┌───┬─────┐│┌─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐│┌───────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐            │┌─────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐                                                                      │
│   ││1│ ││1 1│-1 -1│││1 1 1│-1 -1 1│-1 1 -1│1 -1 -1│││1 1 1 1│-1 -1 1 1│-1 1 -1 1│-1 1 1 -1│1 -1 -1 1│1 -1 1 -1│1 1 -1 -1│            ││1 1 1 1 1│-1 -1 1 1 1│-1 1 -1 1 1│-1 1 1 -1 1│-1 1 1 1 -1│1 -1 -1 1 1│1 -1 1 -1 1│1 -1 1 1 -1│1 1 -1 -1 1│1 1 -1 1 -1│1 1 1 -1 -1│                                                                      │
│   │└─┘ │└───┴─────┘│└─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘│└───────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘            │└─────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘                                                                      │
├───┼────┼───────────┼───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=3│┌──┐│┌────┬────┐│┌──────┬──────┬──────┬────────┐│┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐│┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐               │
│   ││-1│││-1 1│1 -1│││-1 1 1│1 -1 1│1 1 -1│-1 -1 -1│││-1 1 1 1│1 -1 1 1│1 1 -1 1│1 1 1 -1│-1 -1 -1 1│-1 -1 1 -1│-1 1 -1 -1│1 -1 -1 -1│││-1 1 1 1 1│1 -1 1 1 1│1 1 -1 1 1│1 1 1 -1 1│1 1 1 1 -1│-1 -1 -1 1 1│-1 -1 1 -1 1│-1 -1 1 1 -1│-1 1 -1 -1 1│-1 1 -1 1 -1│-1 1 1 -1 -1│1 -1 -1 -1 1│1 -1 -1 1 -1│1 -1 1 -1 -1│1 1 -1 -1 -1│               │
│   │└──┘│└────┴────┘│└──────┴──────┴──────┴────────┘│└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘│└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘               │
├───┼────┼───────────┼───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=4│┌─┐ │┌───┬─────┐│┌─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐│┌───────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────────┐│┌─────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐│
│   ││1│ ││1 1│-1 -1│││1 1 1│-1 -1 1│-1 1 -1│1 -1 -1│││1 1 1 1│-1 -1 1 1│-1 1 -1 1│-1 1 1 -1│1 -1 -1 1│1 -1 1 -1│1 1 -1 -1│-1 -1 -1 -1│││1 1 1 1 1│-1 -1 1 1 1│-1 1 -1 1 1│-1 1 1 -1 1│-1 1 1 1 -1│1 -1 -1 1 1│1 -1 1 -1 1│1 -1 1 1 -1│1 1 -1 -1 1│1 1 -1 1 -1│1 1 1 -1 -1│-1 -1 -1 -1 1│-1 -1 -1 1 -1│-1 -1 1 -1 -1│-1 1 -1 -1 -1│1 -1 -1 -1 -1││
│   │└─┘ │└───┴─────┘│└─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘│└───────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────────┘│└─────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘│
├───┼────┼───────────┼───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=5│┌──┐│┌────┬────┐│┌──────┬──────┬──────┬────────┐│┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐│┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐│
│   ││-1│││-1 1│1 -1│││-1 1 1│1 -1 1│1 1 -1│-1 -1 -1│││-1 1 1 1│1 -1 1 1│1 1 -1 1│1 1 1 -1│-1 -1 -1 1│-1 -1 1 -1│-1 1 -1 -1│1 -1 -1 -1│││-1 1 1 1 1│1 -1 1 1 1│1 1 -1 1 1│1 1 1 -1 1│1 1 1 1 -1│-1 -1 -1 1 1│-1 -1 1 -1 1│-1 -1 1 1 -1│-1 1 -1 -1 1│-1 1 -1 1 -1│-1 1 1 -1 -1│1 -1 -1 -1 1│1 -1 -1 1 -1│1 -1 1 -1 -1│1 1 -1 -1 -1│-1 -1 -1 -1 -1││
│   │└──┘│└────┴────┘│└──────┴──────┴──────┴────────┘│└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘│└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘│
└───┴────┴───────────┴───────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

This definitely shows us the pattern. If K is odd, we get odd number of negations, and if K is even, we get even number of negations. Both can happen up to the amount allowed by the arrays size N. Ie. if K=5, we can get 1 or 3 or 5 negations OR what fits into the array; ie. if N=4, we cannot ofc have 5 negations, but only 1 or 3.

Hence, we can solve this using factorial/binomial (m!n) which tells us the possible number of unique combinations of m elements in n numeric space. Ie. 3!5 would return 10, as there are 10 ways to combine 3 elements of 1,2,3,4,5:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5
```

4!5 would return 5:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 5
1 2 4 5
1 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
```

and 3!3 would return 1:

```
1 2 3
```

The formula for this problem is (2 examples):

```
combinations = (1!6) + (3!6) + (5!6) + (7!6) // K=7, N=6 - note that K is odd
combinations = (0!6) + (2!6) + (4!6) + (6!6) // K=6, N=6 - note that K is even
```

Note:
**0!n is always 1**
**n!n is always 1**
**(>n)!n is always 0** (for example 12!7 would return 0)

To solve this task, execute (again, for a large set, where K = 1...10 and N = 1...14):

```
┌────┬────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┐
│    │N=1                                 │N=2                                 │N=3                                 │N=4                                 │N=5                                 │N=6                                 │N=7                                 │N=8                                 │N=9                                 │N=10                                      │N=11                                      │N=12                                      │N=13                                      │N=14                                      │
├────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=1 │(1!1)                               │(1!2)                               │(1!3)                               │(1!4)                               │(1!5)                               │(1!6)                               │(1!7)                               │(1!8)                               │(1!9)                               │(1!10)                                    │(1!11)                                    │(1!12)                                    │(1!13)                                    │(1!14)                                    │
├────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=2 │(0!1)+(2!1)                         │(0!2)+(2!2)                         │(0!3)+(2!3)                         │(0!4)+(2!4)                         │(0!5)+(2!5)                         │(0!6)+(2!6)                         │(0!7)+(2!7)                         │(0!8)+(2!8)                         │(0!9)+(2!9)                         │(0!10)+(2!10)                             │(0!11)+(2!11)                             │(0!12)+(2!12)                             │(0!13)+(2!13)                             │(0!14)+(2!14)                             │
├────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=3 │(1!1)+(3!1)                         │(1!2)+(3!2)                         │(1!3)+(3!3)                         │(1!4)+(3!4)                         │(1!5)+(3!5)                         │(1!6)+(3!6)                         │(1!7)+(3!7)                         │(1!8)+(3!8)                         │(1!9)+(3!9)                         │(1!10)+(3!10)                             │(1!11)+(3!11)                             │(1!12)+(3!12)                             │(1!13)+(3!13)                             │(1!14)+(3!14)                             │
├────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=4 │(0!1)+(2!1)+(4!1)                   │(0!2)+(2!2)+(4!2)                   │(0!3)+(2!3)+(4!3)                   │(0!4)+(2!4)+(4!4)                   │(0!5)+(2!5)+(4!5)                   │(0!6)+(2!6)+(4!6)                   │(0!7)+(2!7)+(4!7)                   │(0!8)+(2!8)+(4!8)                   │(0!9)+(2!9)+(4!9)                   │(0!10)+(2!10)+(4!10)                      │(0!11)+(2!11)+(4!11)                      │(0!12)+(2!12)+(4!12)                      │(0!13)+(2!13)+(4!13)                      │(0!14)+(2!14)+(4!14)                      │
├────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=5 │(1!1)+(3!1)+(5!1)                   │(1!2)+(3!2)+(5!2)                   │(1!3)+(3!3)+(5!3)                   │(1!4)+(3!4)+(5!4)                   │(1!5)+(3!5)+(5!5)                   │(1!6)+(3!6)+(5!6)                   │(1!7)+(3!7)+(5!7)                   │(1!8)+(3!8)+(5!8)                   │(1!9)+(3!9)+(5!9)                   │(1!10)+(3!10)+(5!10)                      │(1!11)+(3!11)+(5!11)                      │(1!12)+(3!12)+(5!12)                      │(1!13)+(3!13)+(5!13)                      │(1!14)+(3!14)+(5!14)                      │
├────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=6 │(0!1)+(2!1)+(4!1)+(6!1)             │(0!2)+(2!2)+(4!2)+(6!2)             │(0!3)+(2!3)+(4!3)+(6!3)             │(0!4)+(2!4)+(4!4)+(6!4)             │(0!5)+(2!5)+(4!5)+(6!5)             │(0!6)+(2!6)+(4!6)+(6!6)             │(0!7)+(2!7)+(4!7)+(6!7)             │(0!8)+(2!8)+(4!8)+(6!8)             │(0!9)+(2!9)+(4!9)+(6!9)             │(0!10)+(2!10)+(4!10)+(6!10)               │(0!11)+(2!11)+(4!11)+(6!11)               │(0!12)+(2!12)+(4!12)+(6!12)               │(0!13)+(2!13)+(4!13)+(6!13)               │(0!14)+(2!14)+(4!14)+(6!14)               │
├────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=7 │(1!1)+(3!1)+(5!1)+(7!1)             │(1!2)+(3!2)+(5!2)+(7!2)             │(1!3)+(3!3)+(5!3)+(7!3)             │(1!4)+(3!4)+(5!4)+(7!4)             │(1!5)+(3!5)+(5!5)+(7!5)             │(1!6)+(3!6)+(5!6)+(7!6)             │(1!7)+(3!7)+(5!7)+(7!7)             │(1!8)+(3!8)+(5!8)+(7!8)             │(1!9)+(3!9)+(5!9)+(7!9)             │(1!10)+(3!10)+(5!10)+(7!10)               │(1!11)+(3!11)+(5!11)+(7!11)               │(1!12)+(3!12)+(5!12)+(7!12)               │(1!13)+(3!13)+(5!13)+(7!13)               │(1!14)+(3!14)+(5!14)+(7!14)               │
├────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=8 │(0!1)+(2!1)+(4!1)+(6!1)+(8!1)       │(0!2)+(2!2)+(4!2)+(6!2)+(8!2)       │(0!3)+(2!3)+(4!3)+(6!3)+(8!3)       │(0!4)+(2!4)+(4!4)+(6!4)+(8!4)       │(0!5)+(2!5)+(4!5)+(6!5)+(8!5)       │(0!6)+(2!6)+(4!6)+(6!6)+(8!6)       │(0!7)+(2!7)+(4!7)+(6!7)+(8!7)       │(0!8)+(2!8)+(4!8)+(6!8)+(8!8)       │(0!9)+(2!9)+(4!9)+(6!9)+(8!9)       │(0!10)+(2!10)+(4!10)+(6!10)+(8!10)        │(0!11)+(2!11)+(4!11)+(6!11)+(8!11)        │(0!12)+(2!12)+(4!12)+(6!12)+(8!12)        │(0!13)+(2!13)+(4!13)+(6!13)+(8!13)        │(0!14)+(2!14)+(4!14)+(6!14)+(8!14)        │
├────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=9 │(1!1)+(3!1)+(5!1)+(7!1)+(9!1)       │(1!2)+(3!2)+(5!2)+(7!2)+(9!2)       │(1!3)+(3!3)+(5!3)+(7!3)+(9!3)       │(1!4)+(3!4)+(5!4)+(7!4)+(9!4)       │(1!5)+(3!5)+(5!5)+(7!5)+(9!5)       │(1!6)+(3!6)+(5!6)+(7!6)+(9!6)       │(1!7)+(3!7)+(5!7)+(7!7)+(9!7)       │(1!8)+(3!8)+(5!8)+(7!8)+(9!8)       │(1!9)+(3!9)+(5!9)+(7!9)+(9!9)       │(1!10)+(3!10)+(5!10)+(7!10)+(9!10)        │(1!11)+(3!11)+(5!11)+(7!11)+(9!11)        │(1!12)+(3!12)+(5!12)+(7!12)+(9!12)        │(1!13)+(3!13)+(5!13)+(7!13)+(9!13)        │(1!14)+(3!14)+(5!14)+(7!14)+(9!14)        │
├────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│K=10│(0!1)+(2!1)+(4!1)+(6!1)+(8!1)+(10!1)│(0!2)+(2!2)+(4!2)+(6!2)+(8!2)+(10!2)│(0!3)+(2!3)+(4!3)+(6!3)+(8!3)+(10!3)│(0!4)+(2!4)+(4!4)+(6!4)+(8!4)+(10!4)│(0!5)+(2!5)+(4!5)+(6!5)+(8!5)+(10!5)│(0!6)+(2!6)+(4!6)+(6!6)+(8!6)+(10!6)│(0!7)+(2!7)+(4!7)+(6!7)+(8!7)+(10!7)│(0!8)+(2!8)+(4!8)+(6!8)+(8!8)+(10!8)│(0!9)+(2!9)+(4!9)+(6!9)+(8!9)+(10!9)│(0!10)+(2!10)+(4!10)+(6!10)+(8!10)+(10!10)│(0!11)+(2!11)+(4!11)+(6!11)+(8!11)+(10!11)│(0!12)+(2!12)+(4!12)+(6!12)+(8!12)+(10!12)│(0!13)+(2!13)+(4!13)+(6!13)+(8!13)+(10!13)│(0!14)+(2!14)+(4!14)+(6!14)+(8!14)+(10!14)│
└────┴────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

and the result is identical to the the brute-forced one earlier:

```
       N=1  N=2  N=3  N=4  N=5  N=6  N=7  N=8  N=9  N=10  N=11  N=12  N=13  N=14 
 K=1     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13    14 
 K=2     1    2    4    7   11   16   22   29   37    46    56    67    79    92 
 K=3     1    2    4    8   15   26   42   64   93   130   176   232   299   378 
 K=4     1    2    4    8   16   31   57   99  163   256   386   562   794  1093 
 K=5     1    2    4    8   16   32   63  120  219   382   638  1024  1586  2380 
 K=6     1    2    4    8   16   32   64  127  247   466   848  1486  2510  4096 
 K=7     1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  255   502   968  1816  3302  5812 
 K=8     1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256   511  1013  1981  3797  7099 
 K=9     1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256   512  1023  2036  4017  7814 
 K=10    1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256   512  1024  2047  4083  8100
```

These are the total number of unique arrays, after doing the modification K times. Hope this clarifies :-).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have much reputation to comment so i'm asking here.

@Stormwind This won't be the case because array may contain 0 also.